# Return a pointer to an array

Tags: c++, pointers, getter

Suppose you have a class with a private pointer to an array. How can you use a getter to access (or effectively copy the data) so you can access it in a different variable.

```
class MyClass
{
   private:
      double *x;
   public:
      myClass();
      virtual ~MyClass();
      double* getX() const;
      void setX(double* input);
};

MyClass::MyClass()
{
   double foo[2];
   double * xInput;
   foo[0] = 1;
   foo[1] = 2;

   xInput = foo;
   setX(xInput);
}

void MyClass::setX(double * input)
{
   x = input;
}

double * MyClass::getX() const;
{
   return x;
}

int main()
{
   MyClass spam(); // Construct object
   double * bar = spam.getX(); // This doesn't work
}
```

In this case, bar[0] and bar[1] are equal to jibberish: `-9.2559631349317831e+061`.

Comment: I am surprised I couldn't find a similar question on SE, but if someone proves me wrong, close answer ahoy!

Comment: It would help if you'd tell us the error you're getting.

Comment: It's nice to provide the exact compiler output instead of your "this doesn't work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, the program is crashing or showing the wrong output. This is because the constructor is setting a pointer to a local array, which leaves scope and gets destroyed at the end of the constructor.

Comment: So then I how do I fix that in the constructor?

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: MyClass will need a `double foo[2]` member, or you'll have to use dynamic memory.  (For dynamic memory, read farther in your C++ book)

Comment: @Elpezmuerto, you need to initialize the pointer with an array that won't disappear. It can be a member of the class, a static variable, a parameter passed to the constructor, or something allocated with `new`. If you allocate it though you must `delete` it at some point which would require knowing if you own the pointer or if it was provided via setX.

Comment: How can it be a member of the class? Do I need a pointer AND the array full of data?

Comment: @Elpezmuerto, yes you need both if you're going to have a default.

Comment: @MarkRansom, what would that look like then? I am really confused

Comment: @Elpezmuerto, just move your `double foo[2];` from the constructor to the private part of the class declaration.

Answer (score 7):

```
MyClass spam(); // Construct object
```

That does not construct an object, that declares a function called `spam` that takes no arguments and returns a `MyClass`. This default constructs an object:

```
MyClass spam; // Construct object
```

For more information google **the most vexing parse**.

**Update:** As @Mark Ransom pointed out, there is another problem with your code. In your constructor you create an array, and then set `x` to point to such array. However the array lifetime ends once the constructor finishes execution, so further access to `x` would crash (if you are lucky enough).

Comment: And the reason it's so vexing is that it's hard to spot - I certainly missed it. +1

Comment: So concerning that update, how should I set `x` in the constructor?

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: I don't know, just create an array with a longer lifetime. Keep an array as a class member, or create one with `new` and then remember to `delete` it, or...

Comment: If I keep the array as a class member, then how can I return it in the getter? I thought you can't return static arrays for a function

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: You can't return statically sized arrays from a function, but you can return the pointer to which it decays or even better a reference to it (the syntax is a bit odd though).

Comment: @K-ballo, that what I was trying to do (return the pointer), but clearly am failing above

Answer (score 0):

That should probably be *bar instead of bar[0].

Comment: In both C and C++ those are equivalent.